# Can I/how do I use an OnClick with an if statement in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, confirm

I am trying to create a button that when pressed deletes a database entry, when I click it I want a message to say "are you sure you want to delete this" and then if I click cancel the message goes away and nothing happens, if I click okay the deletion runs -- *but also* it reloads the page, I think this will require a jquery(this is what I would like it to be in ) if statement that basically says if ok is clicked then run the default and also refresh the page after the code has run.

so far I have

```
<button name="del" type="submit" value="1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') "> delete</button>
```

Please tell me if I am going the wrong way with this and if I am not, please help me out with how to write the if, (I have infact searched for this and the information is not complete enough for me to understand, I am a PHP developer, never used any Javascript before in my life but would like to start)

EDIT: if this is a caching issue how do I solve it?

Comment: UM, it is a submit button so the page should submit....Why would you need to refresh the page?

Comment: PS Java !== JavaScript

Comment: It does submit, I want it to refresh because that is the way I want it to work.. basically it shows users, and if you click on the delete it deletes them, the page needs to refresh so that you can see the user is not there anymore.

Comment: Can you post the bit which does the deletion? Is it some javascript which deletes an html element, or calls some ajax or what? This will affect how you do "refresh the page after the code has run"

Comment: When the form submits, why is the user still there when the page loads? Are you actually using an Ajax call? There is something weird here.

Comment: I don't know but I am assuming even though it is submitting it isn't refreshing, because if I manually refresh the user is gone.

Comment: @seanyt123 The page will refresh after a normal form submission. I am not sure, but your problem sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: the bit that does deletion is php and is inside of a model in the codeigniter framework, adding it will unnecessarily complicate things

Comment: That sounds like more of a server-side issue, with caching or wrong output. I would go for a [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) approach if you want to load the page fresh and avoid JS altogether.

Comment: well the problem is solved by refreshing so I am still gonna stick to my refreshing solution.

Comment: @seanyt123 Your solution adds an unecessary roundtrip to the server.

Comment: which adds an extra  0.0129 seconds, I think I can manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is more of a caching issue and reloading the page after a form submission is not efficient since you are performing an unneeded roundtrip to the server, however if that's what you want here's one way of doing it:

PS: Remove the `onclick` attribute on your submit button.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    initDeletionPage(document.getElementById('the-id-of-the-form-to-target'));
});

function initDeletionPage(deletionForm) {
    refreshPageIfNeeded();
    deletionForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

    function refreshPageIfNeeded() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('pageRefreshNeeded')) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pageRefreshNeeded');
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    function onSubmit(e) {
        if (!confirmDeletion()) e.preventDefault();
        else indicatePageRefreshNeededAfterSubmission();
    }

    function confirmDeletion() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    }

    function indicatePageRefreshNeededAfterSubmission() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('pageRefreshNeeded', true);
    }
}
```

> Sorry but I asked for a more Jquery way

Ok...

```
$(function () {
    initDeletionPage('#the-id-of-the-form-to-target');
});

function initDeletionPage(deletionForm) {
    refreshPageIfNeeded();
    $(deletionForm).submit(onSubmit);

    function refreshPageIfNeeded() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('pageRefreshNeeded')) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pageRefreshNeeded');
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    function onSubmit(e) {
        if (!confirmDeletion()) e.preventDefault();
        else indicatePageRefreshNeededAfterSubmission();
    }

    function confirmDeletion() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    }

    function indicatePageRefreshNeededAfterSubmission() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('pageRefreshNeeded', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I asked for a more Jquery way :/ also would this allow for the submit confirm (are you sure you want blah blah) on only one button? Because I have another for editting and I don't want that one to ask for confirmation.

Comment: @seanyt123 You have more than one submit button on your form?

Comment: No it's on a different form, does this target a specific form? and is there a way of doing it in Jquery?

Comment: @seanyt123 I updated the code to show you how to target a specific form. Also used jQuery where it made sense... not much advantage here.

Answer (score 1):

The confirmation you have is fine.
However, you're basically performing 2 requests when you press "Ok".

I'd do this one of 2 ways:

1.
Postback to the same page and use PHP to handle the $_POST data before generating the data for the page. Pseudo code:

```
if($_POST['userid']!= null)
    deleteUser($_POST['userid']);
getUsers();
```

2.
Use Javascript to fire an Ajax request to another page which does the deletion of your user. Then on the "Complete" event, get JS to reload the page that you're currently on.

I think option 2 would be best. It will give you some more exposure to JavaScript too.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "deleteuser.php?userid=1",
}).done(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

Or the equivilant for $.post
You don't even need to reload the page. You can use Javascript to remove the row containing the user you just deleted.
This of course uses jQuery, but jQuery is just a wrapper for Javascript